# Assign unique non-repeated ID to nested groups with the same values in R

Tags: r

I have run across similar questions, but have not been able to find an answer for my specific needs.

I have a data set with a nested group design and I need to include a unique non-repeating ID to nested groups that can have identical values. While I regularly conduct this type of data wrangling, both the structure of this data set as well as the required outcome are beyond my skillset at this time.

Below I have provided an example data set (df) and what the results should look like.

I used the below code in my actual data set, but realized that it fails under certain circumstances...which are exaggerated in the example data set provided here. I prefer the ID to be sequentially numbered.

```
df$ID = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df$LENGTH) != 0))
```

I am open to all options (e.g., library(data.table), library(boot), etc) as it would be great if others find this post useful. However, I prefer solutions that do not require the installation and loading of additional packages.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Take care.

```
df <- read.table(text = "GROUP  REGION  TIME    LENGTH
a   x   1   3
a   x   2   3
a   x   3   3
a   y   4   3
a   y   5   3
a   y   6   3
a   z   7   2
a   z   8   2
b   z   1   2
b   z   2   2
b   x   3   2
b   x   4   2
c   x   1   2
c   x   2   2
c   y   3   2
c   y   4   2
c   x   5   2
c   x   6   2
c   z   7   1", header = TRUE)

result <- read.table(text = "GROUP  REGION  TIME    LENGTH  ID
a   x   1   3   1
a   x   2   3   1
a   x   3   3   1
a   y   4   3   2
a   y   5   3   2
a   y   6   3   2
a   z   7   2   3
a   z   8   2   3
b   z   1   2   4
b   z   2   2   4
b   x   3   2   5
b   x   4   2   5
c   x   1   2   6
c   x   2   2   6
c   y   3   2   7
c   y   4   2   7
c   x   5   2   8
c   x   6   2   8
c   z   7   1   9", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste `GROUP` and `REGION` columns and use `rle` to create a sequential `ID` column.

```
transform(df,ID = with(rle(paste(GROUP, REGION)),rep(seq_along(values),lengths)))
```

In `data.table` we can use `rleid`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ID := rleid(GROUP, REGION)]

#    GROUP REGION TIME LENGTH ID
# 1:     a      x    1      3  1
# 2:     a      x    2      3  1
# 3:     a      x    3      3  1
# 4:     a      y    4      3  2
# 5:     a      y    5      3  2
# 6:     a      y    6      3  2
# 7:     a      z    7      2  3
# 8:     a      z    8      2  3
# 9:     b      z    1      2  4
#10:     b      z    2      2  4
#11:     b      x    3      2  5
#12:     b      x    4      2  5
#13:     c      x    1      2  6
#14:     c      x    2      2  6
#15:     c      y    3      2  7
#16:     c      y    4      2  7
#17:     c      x    5      2  8
#18:     c      x    6      2  8
#19:     c      z    7      1  9
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak_Shah! I tried a version of your code...but did not use the `transform` function. Learn something new every day. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option, but without `rle`

```
transform(
  df,
  ID = cumsum(c(1, (s <- paste0(GROUP, REGION))[-1] != head(s, -1)))
)
```

gives

```
   GROUP REGION TIME LENGTH ID
1      a      x    1      3  1
2      a      x    2      3  1
3      a      x    3      3  1
4      a      y    4      3  2
5      a      y    5      3  2
6      a      y    6      3  2
7      a      z    7      2  3
8      a      z    8      2  3
9      b      z    1      2  4
10     b      z    2      2  4
11     b      x    3      2  5
12     b      x    4      2  5
13     c      x    1      2  6
14     c      x    2      2  6
15     c      y    3      2  7
16     c      y    4      2  7
17     c      x    5      2  8
18     c      x    6      2  8
19     c      z    7      1  9
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomaslsCoding! It is good to see mulitple ways to solve this problem with base package. Take care.

Answer (score -1):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
    mutate(ID = rleid(GROUP, REGION))
```